# android Java hashtable failed to store some characters

Tags: java, android, hashtable

I define a hashtable as below:

```
Hashhtable<String, String> dicts = new Hashtable<String, String>();
dicts.put("﻿天", "﻿sky");  
String hashstr =(String)dicts.get("天");
```

However, the return value is null.

I tried with other words, it is ok. But the word "天" cannot be stored, I wonder why? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have different strings. If you copy paste from one string to the other one, it works :

```
Hashtable<String, String> dicts = new Hashtable<>(); // no need to repeat the whole type
dicts.put("天", "sky");  
String hashstr = dicts.get("天"); // no need to cast here
System.out.println(hashstr); // prints "sky"
```

Be careful that Unicode is full of things your editor may not render. More precisely, you have an invisible char at the start of your string (in the call to `put`). An easy way to spot the problem without resorting to an hex editor is to move the cursor in any text editor : it will stay in place at the first hit on the right arrow.

Comment: @ppeterka66: yes, but that's *not* strictly speaking an encoding problem. Non-printable characters are a (necessary) evil in any encoding.

Comment: thank a lot, i really cannot realize that is an "invisible char", thanks for pointing out, save me much debug time!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with putting this character to `Hashtable`. Take look at following

```
    Hashtable<String, String> dicts = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    dicts.put("﻿天", "﻿sky");
    System.out.println(dicts.size());
```

This will print `1`. So now we can see it is storing

May be issue with some thing else.